# Django TypeError/ in views.py (expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list)

Tags: python, django

following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvU4zwO3Ao . Which builds a template on Django server. Pretty confident I followed it precisely, however receiving this error in views.py which is based in the app directory.

Code in Views.py in app directory:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(requests):
    return render(requests, 'home/welcome.html')
```

it's showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "c:\Users\popec\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\mysite\home\views.py", line 5, in home
    return render(requests, 'home/welcome.html')

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 18, in get_template
    for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 36, in get_template_sources
    name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))

File "C:\Users\popec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you template configurations in your settings.py file?

Comment: Yeah here are template configurations in settings.py file: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: OOPS realised there was an extra [] in template settings!

Comment: Is it work now?